# Is there an equivalent of PostgreSQL advisory locks in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql

Is there any way to do in MongoDB something like an advisory lock in PostgreSQL?

I have a certain operation in the DB that requires more than row-level locking can achieve. It can be accessed from multiple processes, so I need a sort of inter-process locking and it would be best to keep it on the DB level.

I have a collection that contains vouchers, and each voucher has a boolean flag indicating whether it was used or not. I need to find a first unused voucher, use it and mark as being used while ensuring that if that operation happens concurrently and many clients are seeking for first unused voucher exactly at the same time there’s no chance that the same voucher will be found and used twice.

That means that **the problem is not about preventing multiple writes** but multiple **reads**. It is not a problem of write locking in Mongo DB, so please avoid linking this question as duplicate to answers about write locks.

Comment: I advice you to read the documentation about [locking](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/)  "MongoDB allows multiple clients to read and write the same data. In order to ensure consistency, it uses locking and other concurrency control measures to **prevent** multiple clients from modifying the same piece of data simultaneously"  "I have a certain operation in the DB that requires more than row-level locking can achieve. It can be accessed from multiple processes" So you should be save.

Comment: I have a collection that contains vouchers, and each voucher has a boolean flag indicating whether it was used or not. I need to find a first unused voucher, use it and mark as being used while ensuring that if that operation happens concurrently and many clients are seeking for first unused voucher exactly at the same time there’s no chance that the same voucher will be found and used twice.